# Create comma separated strings from multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, csv, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that looks like this:

```
[
    Object {href="http://www.somepath.com/car4.png", title="Wheel"},
    Object {href="http://www.somepath.com/car.png", title="Top"},
    Object {href="http://www.somepath.com/car1.png", title="Side"},
    Object {href="http://www.somepath.com/car5.png", title="Saddle"},
    Object {href="http://www.somepath.com/car6.png", title="Front"}
]
```

I'd like to loop over this object and retrieve two comma seperated strings, one for all hrefs and one for all titles. So what I'm after is:

```
hrefs = "'http://www.somepath.com/car4.png', 'http://www.somepath.com/car.png', 'http://www.somepath.com/car1.png', 'http://www.somepath.com/car5.png', 'http://www.somepath.com/car6.png'";
titles = "'Wheel', 'Top', 'Side', 'Saddle', 'Front'";
```

Although it seems pretty easy I lack the knowledge and cant seem to find the specific answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple function that uses [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the values into an array, and then join them up.

```js
const arr=[{href:"http://www.somepath.com/car4.png",title:"Wheel"},{href:"http://www.somepath.com/car.png",title:"Top"},{href:"http://www.somepath.com/car1.png",title:"Side"},{href:"http://www.somepath.com/car5.png",title:"Saddle"},{href:"http://www.somepath.com/car6.png",title:"Front"}];

function createString(arr, key) {
  return arr
    .map(obj => `'${obj[key]}'`)
    .join(', ');
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(createString(arr, 'href')));
console.log(JSON.stringify(createString(arr, 'title')));
```

Additional documentation

- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: @Andy agreed - this is clearly just a "formatted" representation of the object, not actual JS.

Comment: @Andy ok: I was confused by the csv and multi-dimensional array  tags, which are in this case misleading

Comment: I have choosen this as the correct answer as it gives me exactly what I wanted in a clean way.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
var hrefs = [],
    titles = [];

data.forEach(function(obj) {
    hrefs.push("'" + obj.href + "'");
    titles.push("'" + obj.title + "'");
});

hrefs = hrefs.join(', ');
titles = titles.join(', ');
```

Comment: Just a quick note - `forEach` is supported in IE9 and above, in case anybody needs to support previous versions.

Comment: [Here's the polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: @Vld—though a for loop is simple, often faster and can be less to type.

Comment: It really is about time we stopped having to mention polyfills.  ES5 has been out 5 years now - enough is enough!

Comment: When people don't have to support IE8 and lower, perhaps.

Comment: Perhaps, but in the meantime, perhaps we should stop mentioning them _routinely_ and then just have separate questions on SO about "how do I make ES5 functions work on IE8" ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [
    {href:"http://www.somepath.com/car4.png", title:"Wheel"},
    {href:"http://www.somepath.com/car.png", title:"Top"},
    {href:"http://www.somepath.com/car1.png", title:"Side"},
    {href:"http://www.somepath.com/car5.png", title:"Saddle"},
    {href:"http://www.somepath.com/car6.png", title:"Front"}
],
href = [],
title = [],
dataL = data.length;

for ( i = 0; i < dataL; i++ ){
   href.push ( data[i]['href'] );
   title.push ( data[i]['title'] );
}

href = href.join(",");
title = title.join(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

The canonical function to make an array based on the contents of another array is [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).  You can then combine that with `join` to make the required string:

```
var hrefs = data.map(function(d) { return "'" + d.href + "'" }).join(', ');
var titles = data.map(function(d) { return "'" d.title + "'" }).join(', ');
```

Note that this would fail to produce valid CSV if there were any single quote signs inside the fields.  A solution would be to supply a more rigorous quoting function.  Following the usual convention that a quote inside a string should be doubled-up:

```
function enquote(v) {
    return "'" + v.replace(/'/g, "''") + "'";
}
```

with usage:

```
var titles = data.map(function(d) { return enquote(d.title) }).join(', ');
```

Comment: This answer looks fine. Why downvote? care to share the reason please.

Comment: I assume it's because the OP doesn't want an array. The OP wants a string of quoted items.

Comment: @Andy good point - didn't notice that (was distracted by a colleague).  Updated!